# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, async-await

I am trying to write a simple node.js program that will take in a json5 file and convert it to a json file. I have found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-json which I believe will be useful.

This is the code I currently have...

```
const anyJson = require("any-json");

const str = await anyJson.encode({/* test comment */ "foo": "bar"}, 'json');
```

however it gives me this error...

```
const str = await anyJson.encode({/* test comment */ "foo": "bar"}, 'json');
```

(^^^^^ under the await)

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

> Note: This exact code works in the npm runkit

Comment: If you specify the json file value... there's not waiting time... you should use await if you are calling an api or something that will eventually return a value....

Answer (score 0):

Well error is pretty self explanatory. For await to work, it should be within async function.

```
// as you can see await is valid only inside async
async function test() {
   const result = await myfunction()
}

const myfunction = async function(x, y) {
    return anyJson.encode({/* test comment */ "foo": "bar"}, 'json');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Exactly as stated, an await is only valid within an asynchronous function.

If you want to use async/await for a simple program, you can try wrapping the code in an async block that is executed directly

```
const anyJson = require("any-json");

(async () => {
  const str = await anyJson.encode({/* test comment */ "foo": "bar"}, 'json');
  //rest of your code here
})()
```